# Sets and Cartesian products

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I got a question in discrete maths about sets and cartesian products
i need to prove or disprove

`A ∪ (B × C) = (A ∪ B) × (A ∪ C)`

Now my question is how do i compare a regular set and a set of ordered pairs.
do i assume that A is made up of ordered pairs too?
so far i got to:

```
(x,y)| (x,y)∈A v (x,y)∈(B × C)
(x,y)| (x,y)∈A v (x∈B) ^ (y∈C)
(x,y)| ((x,y)∈A v (x∈B)) ^ ((x,y)∈A v y∈C)
```

and now i dont know how to compare between `(x,y)∈A` and `x∈B` i mean one is ordered pair and the other is not and the entire proof is based on A being a set of ordered pairs.. i'd like some explanations here.

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: You do **not** assume that $A$ is a set of ordered pairs. Thus, $A\cup(B\times C)$ may have elements that are not ordered pairs.

Comment: It helps to try a simple example... for instance $A=\{a\},B=\{b\},C=\{c\}$.  It should be clear that the two sides are unequal.  If that argument is unconvincing, then a cardinality argument can work as well.  Assuming no overlap between sets, you have $|A\cup (B\times C)| = |A|+|B|\times |C|$ while $|(A\cup B)\times (A\cup C)| = (|A|+|B|)\times (|A|+|C|)$, clearly a different unequal expression.

Comment: So the same equation with intersection will not be true as well?

Comment: With intersection, both sides *are* sets of ordered pairs, so you need to think about it.  Try some examples.

Comment: "*So the same equation with intersection*"... with intersection in place of what?  The union?  Or in place of the cartesian product?  It *is* true that $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.  It is not true that $A\cap (B\times C) = (A\cap B)\times (A\cap C)$